# Prime number formula proof

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, prime-numbers, inclusion-exclusion

Can anyone please help with this problem?
We have the following formula$$ \pi(n)=n-1+\pi(\lfloor\sqrt{ n }\rfloor)+\sum(-1)^k \lfloor{\frac n {p_{j_1}  p_{j_2}...p_{j_k}}\rfloor} $$ where π(n) is the count of prime numbers from 2 to n (including n). The sum is by the subsets ${\{j_1,j_2,...,j_k\}}$ of $\{1,2,...,\pi{(\lfloor\sqrt{n} \rfloor})\} $
and $k$ is from $1$ to $\pi(\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor).$
We have to prove the formula for each natural number $n$.

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LegendresFormula.html